# How can I split words before and after parenthesis in R?

Tags: r, regex, split

I'm trying to split a text variable that goes like this:

```
text = "name name name (1235-23-532)"
```

to something like this:

```
name = "name name name"
num = "1235-23-532"
```

I'm trying this code:

```
df_split <- df %>%
  separate(owners, 
       into = c("name", "num"), 
       sep = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\\()"
  )
```

However, it results in the number counterpart being NA. I'm confused how it doesn't detect parenthesis (I tried both ( and \( and it doesn't work either way). Is there a good solution for this?

Also: there are some rows that has two parentheses pairs like: "name name name (name) (number)" - any good way to extract just the numbers?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `result <- utils::strcapture("^(.*?)(?:\\s+\\([^0-9()]*\\))?\\s+\\(([0-9-]+)\\)", text, list(f1 = character(), f2 = character()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way how to get your desired output:

```
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(text) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_trim(gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", value)),
         num = str_extract(value, '\\d+\\-\\d+\\-\\d+'), .keep="unused")
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  name           num        
  <chr>          <chr>      
1 name name name 1235-23-532
```

OR:

```
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(text) %>% 
  separate(value, c("name", "num"), sep = ' \\(') %>% 
  mutate(num = str_remove(num, '\\)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way to prevent the "NA", but I do have a workaround I use when I have this problem. I use the mutate `fct_recode` function to the "NA" to equal the proper variable name ([reference](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forcats/versions/0.5.1/topics/fct_recode)).

For example

```
%>% mutate(Column_Name = fct_recode(Column_Name, "new_name" = "NA"))
```

This works for me, it's not perfect but it fixes the problem.